# How to use "responseDecodable" method in Alamofire?

Tags: ios, swift, alamofire, swift5

I have been trying to use "responseDecodable" method from Alamofire, but I'm getting "Generic parameter 'T' could not be inferred" error while using it.
[image: Alamofire]

Can someone guide me how to fix this?

Comment: Please have a look at the [documentation](https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire/blob/master/Documentation/Usage.md#response-handling)

Answer (score 24, accepted):

As you can read in the [documentation](https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire/blob/master/Documentation/Usage.md#response-decodable-handler), using `responseDecodable` is straightforward:

```swift
AF.request(...).responseDecodable(of: ResponseType.self) { response in 
    ...
}
```

Comment: what is ResponseType.self?

Comment: The type you want to decode.